# Button.OnClickListener() gives error

Tags: android

Am new in Android Programming basically am making an app in which when i click 
button the text gonna change... here is my code..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button HimanshuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HimanshuButton);
    HimanshuButton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void OnClick(View v){
                    TextView HimanshuText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HimanshuText);
                    HimanshuText.setText("Great Himanshu Rahi");
```

in this
Button.OnClickListener gives me an error like a red under line..

Comment: It's View.OnClickListener (any View can have a click listener, not just buttons).

Answer (score 2):

A better and neat way to do this will be
Using this method, It will ask you to implement setOnClickListener Interface once you do this HimanshuButton.setOnClickListener(this);

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button HimanshuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HimanshuButton);
    HimanshuButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@override
public void onClick(){
    TextView HimanshuText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HimanshuText);
    HimanshuText.setText("Great Himanshu Rahi");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
new Button.OnClickListener()
```

To:

```
new View.OnClickListener()
```

**UPDATE:**

There's another error: It is `onClick` and not `OnClick`. First letter of `onClick()` must be in lower case.

Full code:

```
Button HimanshuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HimanshuButton);
HimanshuButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView HimanshuText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HimanshuText);
                HimanshuText.setText("Great Himanshu Rahi");
            }
        });
```

Comment: @HimanshuRahi Please, update the question with proper error message then... Same code above works fine.. Also, I added full code..

Answer (score 1):

Do this way for any android widget `ClickListener`

```
Button HimanshuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HimanshuButton);

        HimanshuButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView HimanshuText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HimanshuText);
                HimanshuText.setText("Great Himanshu Rahi");
            }
        });
```

Comment: it woks but i didn't understand hows it work am noob LOL